# Swift: move UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I want to create similar animation for all screen sizes. I have `UIView` in center and want to move at right and distance between `UIView` and screen should be = 10.

How to do it?

My code for one screen(iPhone 5s):

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {

   self.imageRevealed.center.x += 200

})
```

in this case distance between `UIView` and screen = 10. But for other screens I should write new code with new coordinates. How to write universal code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need the trailing space between image view and view of 10px.

```
let trailingSpace: CGFloat = 10
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {

   let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size

   let x = screenSize.width - self.imageRevealed.frame.size.width - trailingSpace
   let y = self.imageRevealed.frame.origin.y

   self.imageRevealed.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: self.imageRevealed.frame.size.width, height: self.imageRevealed.frame.size.height)

})
```

Comment: Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'CGSize' and 'CGFloat'

Comment: Thank you! But I have one question. In storyboard I have `Image Revealed` and `Image Revealed.centerX = centerX - 192` constraint. In `ViewController`I have this code: `UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, delay: 5.0, options: [], animations: { self.ImageRevealedCenterConstraint.constant = 0
        })` but animation doesn't work. When app start `duration` and `delay ` doesn't work. My `Image Revealed` appears in center = without animation.

Comment: write this in animation block `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`

Comment: It is works on iPhone. And `Image Revealed` move from `- 192` at `0` with animation (also I have `Image Revealed.centerY = centerY - 0` constraint in storyboard) .  But on iPad image start move from upper left corner and go in the center. Although `Image Revealed` should be at the vertically center(`Image Revealed.centerY = centerY - 0`) near the left edge of the screen(`Image Revealed.centerX = centerX - 192`).

Comment: Good for iPhone : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKYbh.gif Bad for iPad https://i.stack.imgur.com/788SW.gif